# Get signed integer from 2 16-bit signed bytes?

Tags: c++, binary, byte, signed

So this sensor I have returns a signed value between -500-500 by returning two (high and low) signed bytes. How can I use these to figure out what the actual value is? I know I need to do 2's complement, but I'm not sure how. This is what I have now -

```
real_velocity = temp.values[0];
    if(temp.values[1] != -1)
        real_velocity += temp.values[1];

    //if high byte > 1, negative number - take 2's compliment
    if(temp.values[1] > 1) {
        real_velocity = ~real_velocity;
        real_velocity += 1;
    }
```

But it just returns the negative value of what would be a positive. So for instance, -200 returns bytes 255 (high) and 56(low). Added these are 311. But when I run the above code it tells me -311. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please specify language (and search first).

Comment: I have searched, but I only find stuff about 1 byte and not combining two.

Comment: The title says 16-bit bytes, but the text implies 8-bit bytes. Which is it?

Comment: If they're "16 bit signed bytes" then your job is done.  But I suspect you really have 8-bit bytes like most of the modern world, so you're job is to be shifty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 -200 in hex is 0xFF38,
```

you're getting two bytes 0xFF and 0x38,
converting these back to decimal you might recognise them

```
0xFF = 255,
0x38 = 56
```

your sensor is not returning 2 signed bytes but a simply the high and low byte of a signed 16 bit number.

so your result is

```
value = (highbyte << 8) + lowbyte
```

value being a 16 bit signed variable.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example you gave, it appears that the value is already 2's complement. You just need to shift the high byte left 8 bits and OR the values together.

```
real_velocity = (short) (temp.values[0] | (temp.values[1] << 8));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the bits and mask the values.

```
int main()
{
    char data[2];
    data[0] = 0xFF; //high
    data[1] = 56; //low
    int value = 0;

    if (data[0] & 0x80) //sign
        value = 0xFFFF8000;

    value |= ((data[0] & 0x7F) << 8) | data[1];

    std::cout<<std::hex<<value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::dec<<value<<std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Output:

ffffff38

-200

Comment: I don't think the extra masking is needed.  If you bit-shift the high value as an `unsigned char` into an `unsigned short` and then `OR` the low value as an `unsigned char` into that, and then reinterpret the result as a `signed short`, the result is a signed -200.

Answer (score 0):

```
real_velocity = temp.values[0];
real_velocity = real_velocity << 8;
real_velocity |= temp.values[1];
// And, assuming 32-bit integers
real_velocity <<= 16;
real_velocity >>= 16;
```

Answer (score 0):

For 8-bit bytes, first just convert to `unsigned`:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;
unsigned const u = (Byte( temp.values[1] ) << 8) | Byte( temp.values[0] );
```

Then if that is greater than the upper range for 16-bit two's complement, subtract 2<sup>16</sup>:

```
int const i = int(u >= (1u << 15)? u - (1u << 16) : u);
```

You could do tricks at the bit level, but I don't think there's any point in that.

The above assuming that `CHAR_BIT` = 8, that `unsigned` is more than 16 bits, and that the machine and desired result is two's complement.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef unsigned char Byte;
    struct { char values[2]; } const temp = { 56, 255 };

    unsigned const  u = (Byte( temp.values[1] ) << 8) | Byte( temp.values[0] );
    int const       i = int(u >= (1u << 15)? u - (1u << 16) : u);

    cout << i << endl;
}
```